# A book that talks of how computer hardware is designed

Tags: education

There are many books aboout what CPU's pipelines do and etc., but I am unable to find a book that talks of how computer hardware is designed - technical stuff, like electrical engineering stuff. Can anyone recommend some book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Computer Arithmetic: Algorithms and Hardware Designs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195328485)
- [Computer Engineering: Hardware Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131629263)
- [The principles of computer hardware](http://books.google.com/books?id=Jd9GAQAAIAAJ)
- [Logic and Computer Design Fundamentals](http://books.google.com/books?id=XTdED7sy03cC)

Answer (score 0):

["Code" by Charles Petzold](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735611319). Not just how a computer is built, how one is derived.